# Validate position of @ symbol in email with Javascript

Tags: javascript, validation

I need to validate the position of the @ symbol when the form is submitted.
If Email address is not in the following format
‘@’ position<1 OR ‘ .’position< ’@’ position+2 OR ‘.’position+2>= Email length an alert should pop up

Comment: you're probs not the first one with this issue

Comment: regex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to validate an email address in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something similar to this to validate the email manually using given conditions.

```
function validateEmail() {
  var emailInput = document.getElementById('email');
  var atPos = emailInput.value.indexOf("@");
  var dotPos = emailInput.value.indexOf(".");
  var emailLength = emailInput.value.length;
  if (atPos < 1 || dotPos < atPos + 2 || dotPos + 2 > emailLength) {
    alert("Invalid Email format");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

BTW always **recommended** to use [regex method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript) since it's the proper way to do these type of validations.